# Logical error in my SqlCode

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to run a report that give the count of record with specific createria Per Month.For each Month my query display the month more than once. Could it be that am doing something wrong: My script:

```
Select DATEPART(mm,DatePrinted),COUNT(ReceiptNo)As CardPrinted
from mytble where ReceiptNo like'990%'
Group by DatePrinted
```

posible receipts:800,75.
Am expected something like:

January  totalcount

Feb      totalcount etc.

Comment: You want to group january 2012 and january 2013 together or separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group by DATEPART(month,DatePrinted)`.

```
Select DATEPART(month,DatePrinted) As MyMonth, COUNT(ReceiptNo) As CardPrinted
From mytble 
Where ReceiptNo like '990%'
Group by DATEPART(month,DatePrinted)
```

If you need name of the month, then use `DATENAME()` function:

```
Select DATENAME(month,DatePrinted) As MyMonth, COUNT(ReceiptNo) As CardPrinted
From mytble 
Where ReceiptNo like '990%'
Group by DATENAME(month,DatePrinted)
```

**Note:** May be you need to group by year to get correct results. Otherwise, you will get the count of similar months regardless of the year. If you are looking for a particular year, add this filter to the `WHERE` clause `Year(DatePrinted) = yourYear`

Answer (score 3):

Your group by statement is wrong, it must be on `DATEPART(mm,DatePrinted)`

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm, DatePrinted) AS [Month], COUNT(ReceiptNo) As CardPrinted
FROM mytble 
WHERE ReceiptNo LIKE '990%'
GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, DatePrinted)
```

You can also replace `COUNT(ReceiptNo)` by `COUNT(*)`.

Also note that as it is right now, all months of different years will be grouped together.

If that isin't the desired behaviour you can `SELECT` and `GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, DatePrinted), DATEPART(mm, DatePrinted)`